# Double click event for a select tag. issue with Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, select, double-click

I have a **select** element and i need an event to fire when i **double click** on it.
Here is the html code

```
<select  class='my_field' unselectable='on'  onselectstart='return false;' onmousedown='return false;'>
<option value="test">test</option>
</select>
```

And here is the JavaScript code

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {


         $(".my_field").dblclick(function(e)
             {
             alert('double click');
             });

});
```

In browsers like IE or Chrome this event works ok. **But not in Firefox**.

I prepared a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmozqmLt/1/). In this jsfiddle i have also added a text input to show that the event works good for fields other than select tag, **even in FF**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if dblclick is a standard event.

But you can easily implement it with a few more code (not tested):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    (function(){ // Closure. Not needed if this is the only code.
        var dblClickMs = 1000; // One second. Adjust at your needings.
        var fld = $(".my_field");
        var t0 = 0;

        fld.on("click", function(){
            var t = (new Date()).getTime();
            if (t - t0 <= dblClickMs) {
                alert('double click');
            } else {
                t0 = t;
            };
        });
    })();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for writing this code. I just replaced the "more or equal"(>=) with "less or equal"(<=) and now it works.  If no other answers will be posted, i will accept your solution and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Ooops! This occasionally happen when you don't test your code :-D

Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I thought jQuery was completely cross browser, native javascript seems to work and at least you dont need to mimic an actual double click event.

```
function doubleclick(){
    alert('double click');
}

$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".my_field").each(function(){

        var element = this;
        if (this.addEventListener) {
            element.addEventListener('dblclick', doubleclick , false);
        } else {
            element.attachEvent('ondblclick', function() {
                return(doubleclick.call(element, window.event));   
            });
        } 
    });
});
```